# How much knowledge is needed to create a video game Mario (Nes version) in java?

Tags: java

I want to be able to create video games in java. Programming video games a lot of topics. so far one month in the java class, I've learned about how to create objects out of java. However with the knowledge I learned,  I don't have an idea how to create a video game like Mario for the Nintendo Entertainment System. What programming topics are involved in creating such software in java?

I've made a basic button based game that involved 400 lines of code in Visual Basic but I want to be able to create graphical application that involves animations.

Comment: A couple of years of study at least are required, but this isn't really a question answerable on SO.

Comment: Mario is pretty advance. Maybe try something easier first. Source: http://compsci.ca/blog/12-computer-science-game-project-ideas/

Answer (score 4):

You should get to a point where you understand an introduction to Java book completely.

On the topic of java game programming books, Developing Games in Java by David Brackeen is a superior choice when compared to Killer Game Programming In Java, with the goal of wanting to create a mario-esque type game kept in mind. Killer Game Programming In Java uses some bad techniques for their 2D platformer, while Brackeen goes all out in his 2D platformer example, and uses all the correct good techniques.

I've read and own both books. Link to Brackeen's book:

http://www.brackeen.com/javagamebook/

Can't seem to post this, maybe because I don't have an account? Get the message:
Little slab of meat / In a wash of clear jelly / Now I heat the pan

Comment: welcome to SO, interesting comment +1

Comment: Thanks, how come this guy's question got -1 and closed?

Comment: From [SO FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq): "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.". This question is probably more appropriate on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/), however it should also made more practical, for instance asking for how to learn,  rather than "how much knowledge", that is difficult to answer.

Comment: Eh, doesn't sound too difficult to interpret what this guy is asking, the guy's question can just be read as "What should I learn to program mario etc etc". Question seems pretty valid, but oh well.

Answer (score 0):

First learn more on the basics of programming and then get a book on game programming.

Depends on the type of game but technologies like [OpenGL or DirectX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756709/game-programming-book-using-opengl-and-directx) can give interesting results.

There is a book called [Killer Game Programming in Java](http://fivedots.coe.psu.ac.th/~ad/jg/). I didn't read it, so I don't know if is good or not, but you may want to take a look at it.

**How much knowledge is needed?** Difficult to answer, if you persevere your games will get better and better. However game programming is often a team effort, requiring people with different backgrounds. Hovercraft said two years, I'd say start small, keep on improving, it will take 10 years to be an expert. Doesn't mean that you've to study for 10 years, if you're lucky enough to get a job that coincides with your passion, you'll keep on learning on your job.